# Create concrete type for abstract property depending on context

Tags: c#, unit-testing, autofixture

I have the following type hierarchy:

```
public abstract class ResourceId
{
}

public class CarId : ResourceId
{
}

public class PlaneId: ResourceId
{
}

public interface IResource
{
  ResourceId Id { get; set; }
}

public class Plane : IResource
{
  public ResourceId Id { get; set; }
}

public class Car : IResource
{
  public ResourceId Id { get; set; }
}
```

I want AutoFixture to create the 'right' type of ResourceId when it tries to create a Plane or Car.

I tried using:

```
_fixture.Customize<Plane>(composer => 
    composer.With(h => h.Id, _fixture.Create<PlaneId>()));
```

But of course that creates the same ID for each instance. I want each to have a unique ID.

What is the best approach for this?

Answer (score 5):

There's a way to do what you ask for but it requires a *lesser-known* customization API: the [`Register`](https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture/blob/master/Src/AutoFixture/FixtureRegistrar.cs) method.

The purpose of `Register` is to allow the user to specify a **factory function** for a specific type. AutoFixture will then delegate the creation of objects of that type to the function.

One distinctive feature of `Register` is that it's able to provide *anonymous objects to pass as arguments to the factory function* whenever they're needed. It does so through a number of overloads. Here are [a few examples](https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture/blob/master/Src/AutoFixtureDocumentationTest/Intermediate/RegisterExample.cs):

- `Register<T>(Func<T> factory)` doesn't provide any arguments to the factory
- `Register<T1, T>(Func<T1, T> factory)` provides one argument of type `T1` to create objects of type `T`
- `Register<T1, T2, T>(Func<T1, T2, T> factory)` provides two arguments of type `T1` and `T2` to create objects of type `T`

Now, we can use this feature to customize the way objects of type `Car` and `Plane` are created by assigning anonymous instances of `CarId` and `PlanId` to their `Id` properties:

```
[Fact]
public void Test()
{
    var fixture = new Fixture();
    fixture.Register<CarId, Car>(id =>
    {
        var resource = new Car { Id = id };
        return resource;
    });
    fixture.Register<PlaneId, Plane>(id =>
    {
        var resource = new Plane { Id = id };
        return resource;
    });

    Assert.NotSame(fixture.Create<Car>().Id, fixture.Create<Car>().Id);
    Assert.NotSame(fixture.Create<Plane>().Id, fixture.Create<Plane>().Id);
}
```

This test passes because the `CarId` and `PlanId` objects that are passed to the factory functions are *created by AutoFixture*, thus being different every time.

Comment: I think this may be heading toward the best approach, but I do not want to use my own factory...I want AF to create the Car/Plane but override setting of the Id property. I guess I can do that manually in the lambda, but AF will try to assign something to the Id first?

Answer (score 5):

Here's a simple way to do what you want:

```
[Fact]
public void HowToUseFixtureToCreatePlanesWithNewIds()
{
    var fixture = new Fixture();
    fixture.Customize<Plane>(c => c
        .Without(p => p.Id)
        .Do(p => p.Id = fixture.Create<PlaneId>()));

    var planes = fixture.CreateMany<Plane>();

    Assert.True(planes.Select(p => p.Id).Distinct().Count() > 1);
}
```

However, if I were you, I'd seriously consider simplifying that class hierarchy...

Comment: This is the solution I used but it didn't seem as elegant as it could/should be. But then again, as you say, I think my question resulted from an inelegant hierarchy to begin with...

Answer (score 1):

You have to customize the creation algorithm for each class, in this example `Car` and `Plane`, as the following passing test demonstrates:

```
[Fact]
public void Test()
{
    var fixture = new Fixture();
    fixture.Customize<Plane>(c => c
        .With(x => x.Id, fixture.Create<PlaneId>()));
    fixture.Customize<Car>(c => c
        .With(x => x.Id, fixture.Create<CarId>()));

    var plane = fixture.Create<Plane>();
    var car = fixture.Create<Car>();

    Assert.IsType<PlaneId>(plane.Id);
    Assert.IsType<CarId>(car.Id);
}
```

Comment: That's gives the problem I already described: It creates the same IDs. I want a unique ID per instance.

Comment: I apologize, it looks that I didn't fully understand your issue. Could you please try the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25522584/467754) that Enrico Campidoglio provided?